# controls that have items , wpf

Tags: wpf-controls

I want to be able to get a control that i don't know in advance what type is it and to be able to go through it's items collection . The problem is that each control wants it's own casting and i don't know how to do it generic...... if the control doesn't have items i want to use just this control.... 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could work. A Control is a [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx), and if that object inherits IEnumerable, it will have an iterator.

```
        private void DoStuffWithControl(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        if (dependencyObject is IEnumerable)
        {
            IEnumerator enumerator = (dependencyObject as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // Do whatever you want to do with the item (enumerator.Current)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the control
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed my code according to your suggestion but the iterator doesn't iterate through the items collection , it doesn't even go into the while , like the control doesn't have any items.... very strange...